# Редактирование записей в MySQL через PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Всем привет. Есть страница, на которой выводится таблица оборудования (название, сетевое имя, комплектация, и т.д.) Надо улавливать radio, и редактировать только ту строку, которая отмечена.

**Последовательность:**

1. определяем строку
2. открываем всплывающее окно
3. выводим ранее введённые значения
4. в этих же формах ввода пишем новые значения (любые)
5. сохраняем
6. всплывающее окно закрывается

**Сама страница:**

```
<?php
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");

define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/connect.php');

$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `applications` ORDER BY `id`") or die(mysql_error());

$text = '
<br />
<center><table border="1" style="width:100%;" class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>№</th>
        <th>Комната</th>
        <th>Ф.И.О</th>
        <th>IP</th>
        <th>Неисправность</th>
        <th>Характеристика неисправности</th>
        <th>Дата заявки</th>
        <th>Дата выполнения</th>
        <th>Коментарий</th>
        <th>Статус</th>
        <th><input type="checkbox" id="selall" value="1" class="checkbox"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
$text .= '
    <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['room'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['regIP'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['device'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['defect'].'</td>
            <td>'.date('d.m.Y', $row['created_date']).'</td>
            <td>'.$row['date_completed'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['comment'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['status'].'</td>
            <td><input  type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="" name="ip[]"></td>
        </tr>';

}
$text .= '';
$text = str_replace('1900-01-01','<span style="color:blue">Не выдан</span>',$text);
echo $text;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к. у Вас всё уже полученно из базы и содержится в html коде страницы, то на мой взгляд алгоритм примерно следующий:
Рекомендую использовать [jQuery](http://jquery-docs.ru/)

1. Изменяете содержимое html в нужных полях(по средствам открывающегося окна, как его организовать можно найти на просторах интернета) изменяя содержимое тега.
2. Потом, по нажатии кнопки сохранить, тем же jQuery достаём содержимое таблицы и при помощи $.toJSON преобразуем наши данные в JSON и передаём их PHP скрипту, который эту строку encode_json, далее обычный парсинг строки и формирование SQL запроса UPDATE

Дополнения:
 1. У Вас в переменной `$text` уже содержатся прочитанные данные из таблицы MySQL. Эта переменная выводится после выполнения вышеприведённого скрипта. На этом этапе php заканчивается. 
 2. что бы изменять значения, то рекомендую данные выводить несколько иначе, чем вы делаете
 например: 
Вы пишете `<td>'.$row['id'].'</td>` а так вы не измените данные из браузера, 
а так 
`<td><INPUT TYPE=TEXT SIZE=40 NAME=id value="'.$row['id'].'"> </td>`
 сможете поменять.
3. Нажав на кнопку сохранить, получите данные из input средствами jQuery и дальше как я писал выше toJSON и т.д.

Comment: А можно поподробнее про:<br />
1) выводим ранее введённые значения
2) в этих же формах ввода пишем новые значения (любые)
3) сохраняем